# Including newlines in ls output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Practicing some Bash scripting:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 read -p "Input the path to a file or directory: " TARGET_PATH
  4 
  5 if [ -f "${TARGET_PATH}" ]
  6 then
  7     echo "${TARGET_PATH} is a file!"
  8     echo $(ls ${TARGET_PATH} -l)
  9 elif [ -d "${TARGET_PATH}" ]
 10 then
 11     echo "${TARGET_PATH} is a directory!"
 12     echo $(ls ${TARGET_PATH} -l)
 13 else
 14     echo "${TARGET_PATH} is not a file or directory."
 15 fi
```

This works as intended if `TARGET_PATH` is a file, the `ls -l` command runs against it fine enough.

But if it's a directory, the output of `ls -l` squishes many items into one line.

I tried iterating over the `ls -l` command in that instance but it split everything by spaces so every single piece ended up on a new line.

Is there a way to output the contents similar to what we'd expect it to do had we entered `ls -l` at the terminal?

Comment: Change `echo $(ls ${TARGET_PATH} -l)` to `ls -l "${TARGET_PATH}"`

Comment: @anubhava of course!! Thanks, I completely forgot that I can just write the commands directly as if I were writing this in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-1` option (that's a number one, not a lowercase L) to `ls` will make it output one item per line.

```
ls -1l "${TARGET_PATH}"
```